# Clone and append on click makes multiple elements and toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to clone and append elements. after i append i have added a `toggle` animation. on first click it works fine. after i am getting mutliple elements appended.

as well the animation not working.

here is the html:

```
<div class="parent hide">
    <div class="header">
        <h6>Header</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>paragraph content </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">

</div>

<button>Add</button>
```

Js :

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.header', function () {
    $(this).find('h6').toggleClass('name').end()
    .siblings('.content').slideToggle();
});

$('button').on('click', function () {
   var newParent = $('.parent').clone();
   $('#content').append(newParent.removeClass('hide'));
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LHcgp/120/)

**UPDATE:**

I updated the cloning passing `var newParent = $('.parent').clone(true);` - animation works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should clone only the first element (or the last for that matter):

```
var newParent = $('.parent:first').clone(true);
```

## [**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/LHcgp/125/)

Using `.clone(true)` seems to fix the animation. Another solution is targeting the parent on click and delegating `.parent .header` since the cloned `.parent` is being added to the DOM after the initial load:

```
$('#content ').on('click', '.parent .header', function () {
```

instead of

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.header', function () {
```

## [**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/LHcgp/128/)

Answer (score 1):

Cloning an elements means there will be two identical elements (having the same class aswell) afterwards.

Each time you click the button, all elements having the .parent class are cloned and appended to the #content

**Regarding the animation:**

The appended elements are not known to the DOM, so the .on('click') is not working.
Try to put a wrapper around your .parent elements and then use the following syntax:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent hide">
        <div class="header">
            <h6>Header</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>paragraph content </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

    </div>
</div>

<button>Add</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.parent .header', function(){ [...] });
```

Comment: Sure, it's completely fine.
I'm just saying why he's having more and more divs each time he clicks the button.